# Using eye drops during fast as a medicine

Tags: fiqh, sawm, ramadan, medical

if we use eye drops during fast will it break the fast or not. some people says that it breaks the fast and some says that it does not break the fast. kindly someone solve my confusion related to this problem i use eye drops as medicine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to use the eyes drop in night when you are going to be sleep. 
But if you put drops in the morning or day timing while you fasting also then your fast is broken. Because when you use any eye drops and injections eyes are connected to your throat when you put some drops into your eyes you can feel the taste of drop which becomes the reason of fast expiring.
If you capable to spit out the liquid than your fast is not broken.

Answer (score 2):

The application of eye drops in one's eyes does not invalidate the fast, even if the taste of the eye drops can be felt in the mouth and throat.If any one felt the taste of that particular drop in the mouth and throat then of course the eye drop invalidate the fast otherwise not.

Comment: Your first and second sentences are contradicting each other.

Answer (score 0):

Medicated `ear` and `nose drops` not permissible for those on fast. ... However, the use of eye drops while fasting is **deemed permissible** as per the fatwa.

The department's fatwas are meant to help Muslims observe their Ramadan fast in the right manner. Muslim scholars, however, differ about using eye drops while fasting.Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah was of the view that kohl does not break the fast, not even if the taste of the kohl reaches the throat. He said, this is not called food or drink, and it is not like food or drink, and it does not have the same effect as food or drink. There is no saheeh hadeeth from the `Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)` which expressly indicates that kohl breaks the fast, and the basic principle is that it does not break the fast.

But if you feel taste in your throat try to avoid its usage during fast; else choice is urz